# Firestore gives ERROR FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions. even though works fine in rules playground

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am using phone authentication in firestore. But when i set following security rules it works fine in the firestore playground but gives me error in the frontend.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /user_login_details/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

When i remove the if statement it works fine but does not work with if. Phone number along with it's UID is present in the authentication section.

Clientside code: I am getting the phone number on successful auth and passing it to check if a user exist or not

```
this.firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged().subscribe((res) => {
    if (res) {
      this.chkUserExistOrNot(res.phoneNumber.substr(1));
    }
});

chkUserExistOrNot(user_phone_number) {
   this.authservice.getUserData(user_phone_number).subscribe((res) => {
      if (res.length > 0) { // do something }
      else { // do something } 
   });
}

getUserData(number) {
        return this.db.collection<login>('user_login_details', ref => ref.where("phone", "==", number)).snapshotChanges().pipe(map(
            actions => {
                return actions.map(a => {
                    const data = a.payload.doc.data();
                    const id = a.payload.doc.id;
                    return { id, ...data };
                });
            }
        ), first());
    }
```

Update** The getCurrentUser() method returns null inside onAuthStateChanged().

Comment: Rules by themselves don't mean very much.  They must be paired with code that should be allowed or rejected.  Please edit the question to show the client code that isn't working the way you expect.  Also be sure to show that you know for sure that there is an authenticated user making the request.

Comment: @DougStevenson i am new to firestore and my understanding is that if the phone number is present with UID in the auth section then it should work. I might be wrong. I have edited the question.

Comment: That code doesn't look like a Firestore query to me.  If it's not a Firestore query, then security rules don't apply. A Firestore query would have code that accesses the `user_login_details` collection.

Comment: @DougStevenson Edited with the query

Comment: And how are you certain that a user is currently signed in at the time of the query, as your rules require?  If no user is signed in, then the rule will reject the query.

Comment: @DougStevenson At first glance, the `if (res) {` seems to ensure that `chkUserExistOrNot` and `getUserData` only run if the user is signed in.

Comment: I have used onAuthStateChanged() of phone number authentication where i will receive the phone number only if the user has signed in, which i have passed to the query.

Comment: Is there something i need to do from client side or am i missing something. I don't understand why it is failing.

Comment: How are you observing a failure?  Please be specific about the error message.

Comment: When i try to put any of the if statement with request, for ex- request.auth != "null" or request.auth.uid != "null", i get "ERROR FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions." error message. rules works fine when i remove the condition statements.

Comment: It also does not show any error in the rule playground when tried with same number and uid.

Comment: when i execute getCurrentUser() it returns null inside chkUserExistOrNot(). But it executes only after if condition of onAuthStateChanged() is true. what might be the issue!!